# Truncate Substring from middle for NSString

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring

How can we truncate substring from NSString from middle
Let say, i have NSString
NSString *str = @"Thu 25 Nov 2014 /Shared/Documents/Drawing/c"
I want to truncate path string from middle & show that on label.For This i am using NSStrinbuteString on label

```
NSString *path = @"/Shared/Documents/Drawing/c";
NSString *date = @"Thu 25 Nov 2014";
NSString *wholeString = self.descLabel.text;
NSRange pathRange = [wholeString rangeOfString:path];
NSRange range=NSMakeRange(pathRange.location,path.length);

NSMutableParagraphStyle* style= [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
style.lineBreakMode= NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle;


NSMutableAttributedString* str=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString: self.descLabel.text];
[str addAttribute: NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value: style range: range];
self.descLabel.attributedText= str;
```

This doesnt seems to be doing anything.Cn anyone suggest if i am doing something wrong

Comment: If it's a UILabel, why don't you set the linebreakmode directly on the UIlabel instead as a simply text, without using an attributed string ?

Answer (score 1):

A not so optimized example using very simple regex. This example requires the path to start with a forward slash and also that the path always is last.

```
NSString *test = @"Thu 25 Nov 2014 /Shared/Documents/Drawing/c";
NSString *resultPath = @"";
// Create a range for it. We do the replacement on the whole
// range of the text, not only a portion of it. This can be optimized.
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, test.length);

NSError *errors = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(/.*)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive|NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators error:&errors];

NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:test options:NSMatchingProgress range:range];
if(matches.count == 1 && !errors) {
    NSTextCheckingResult* result = matches[0];
    // One result found
    resultPath = [test substringWithRange:result.range];
} else {
    // many results found or error
}
```

resultPath will now contain: "/Shared/Documents/Drawing/c".

Now you can simply add the result to your label or add it to an attributed string for more customization abilities like you already have done.

As i said in the beginning. This is one very basic regex example..

Comment: The OP seems to just want to identify the range of the path so that attributes can be applied to that part of the attributed string.  I think the question's title is misleading.

Comment: True. `result.range` contains the searched for range.

Comment: OK then.  The OP's code doesn't look too bad in terms of finding the range, and to further mislead us I think they want to know why the `NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle` attribute has no effect.

Comment: @trojanfoe you are so right. I read the question again and yes, it's not that good written, but I'll leave the answer for future reference.

Comment: Upvote for effort and attitude as well as decent code.